# Using MailMessage Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

i'm using MailMessage class  to send emails

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(fromAddr, toAddr);
```

when i create the new MailMessage object it automatically gets the host using the fromAddr.for an example,if my fromaddress is chamara@pindoc.com.au it assumes the host as pindoc.com.au but i have a different name for the host.so the host name is wrong.i think because of that i'm getting the following error.

{"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"} System.Exception {System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException}

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your [`mailSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? Example web.config below:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="no-reply@yourdomain.com">
      <network defaultCredentials="true" host="mail.yourdomain.com" port="25"/>
   </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the mail server when you create an instance of the SmtpClient object (as well as other details like port numbers and authentication)

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("different.hostname"); // specify your hostname
client.Send(msg);
```

You could also specify your [smtp details in the web.config or app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and the SmtpClient will pick these up automatically...

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, i'll use [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send messages. It's constructor takes a host and port:

```
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 25);
mailClient.Send(msg);
```